# Cocos2d CCMenuItem target gives SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create a menu system that calls a method depending on what is pressed. The problem is when I add a target and selector to the CCMenuitems.It crashes with a sgabrt error. I know the problem is something to do with the target, but what should it be? Here is my .h and .m code

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

// splashMenuLayer
@interface splashMenuLayer : CCLayer
{
BOOL menuButtonsShowing;
CCLabelTTF * splashLabel;
CCMenuItemFont * puzzleMenuItem;
CCMenuItemFont * raceMenuItem;
CCMenuItemFont * leaderboardMenuItem;
CCMenu * mainMenu;
}

// returns a CCScene that contains the HelloWorldLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene;
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void) deleteLabel :(id)sender;
-(void) puzzleMode:(id)sender;
-(void) raceMode:(id)sender;
-(void) Leaderboard:(id)sender;

@property BOOL menuButtonsShowing;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelTTF* splashLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenuItem* puzzleMenuItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenuItem* raceMenuItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenuItem* leaderboardMenuItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenu* mainMenu;

@end
```

and finally

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if (menuButtonsShowing == NO) {
    id action = [CCSequence actions:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(deleteLabel:)], nil];
    [splashLabel runAction:action];

//create the menu items and all the target/selector
    puzzleMenuItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Puzzle Mode" target:self selector:@selector(puzzleMode:)];
    raceMenuItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Race Mode" target:self selector:@selector(raceMode:)];
    leaderboardMenuItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Leaderboard" target:self selector:@selector(leaderboard:)];

//add the menu items to the menu
    mainMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:puzzleMenuItem, raceMenuItem, leaderboardMenuItem, nil];
    [mainMenu alignItemsVertically];
    mainMenu.position = ccp(240, 100);


    [self addChild:mainMenu];
    }
}

-(void) puzzleMode:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"lol1");
}
-(void) raceMode:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"lol2");
}
-(void) Leaderboard:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"lol3");
```

}

Comment: Do you have a deleteLabel: method in your .m as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct this line  with capital L

```
leaderboardMenuItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Leaderboard" target:self selector:@selector(leaderboard:)];
```

to

```
     leaderboardMenuItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Leaderboard" target:self selector:@selector(Leaderboard:)];
```

Comment: Yeah a typo in your selector will screw runtime always.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I've been able to spot is that `@selector(leaderboard:)` should be `@selector(Leaderboard:)` (capitalized).

Mike